# How to use yarn workspaces with typescript and out folders?

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to set up a monorepo using yarn.  I'm confused as to how to set up typescript with project references such that things resolve properly.

For example, if I have a folder structure like

```
/cmd
/client
```

And I want `cmd` to depend on `client` I could have:

`cmd/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["reflect-metadata", "jest"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "composite": true,
    "target": "esnext"
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../client"
    }
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

with a `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "cmd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "client": "^1.0.0",
  }
}
```

In this model both `cmd` and `client` get compiled with an `outDir` and `sourceRoot` field set in their tsconfig. This means all their compiled javascript goes into the `dist/` subfolder of `cmd/dist` and `client/dist`

If now I try and reference a class from `client` into `cmd` like

```
import Foo from 'client/src/foo'
```

The IDE is perfectly happy to resolve this since it seems that its mapped via the typescript `references` property.

However, the compiled javascript boils down to a

```
const foo_1 = require("client/src/foo");
```

However, the actual built javascript is in `client/dist/src/foo`, so at runtime this never works.

On the flip side, if I don't use sourceRoots and outDirs and have the javascript inlined with the typescript files at the same folder everything does work (but makes the repo dirty and requires custom gitignores to exclude things)

Can anyone shed any light on how to properly set up a typescript 3.x monorepo with yarn workspaces such that things just work?

Comment: Sidenote: I used [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to setup a monorepo and found it quite worthile and it should also work with yarn. (I used it with npm.)

Comment: I remember dealing with something like this.   If you want to post a repository link, that reproduces the problem, I'll take a look.

Comment: take a look at this repo. They have done it quit well.  look through it https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I created a Github [Repository](https://github.com/a1300/devshorts_yarn_workspace_typescript_example) to make it easier to follow the following code description:

### Code Description

TypeScript `Project References` make it possible to compile a TypeScript project that consist of multiple smaller TypeScript projects, each project having a `tsconfig.json` file. (Source: [Project References Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html))

#### TypeScript Setup

We have a root `tsconfig.json` file that only manages its sub-projects. The `references` property specifies the directories that each contain a valid `tsconfig.json` file. If we now build the project with the `--build` option (`tsc --build tsconfig.json`) then we specified the projects which should be compiled, but we didn't specified the **build order** in which the projects should be compiled.

```
{
  "references": [
    { "path": "./client" },
    { "path": "./cmd" }
  ],
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules"]
}
```

To correctly specify the **build order** we need to add a `references` property to the **`cmd/tsconfig.json`** file. This tells the compiler that it first needs to compile `client/` before we compile `cmd/`:

`cmd/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.packages.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../client"
    }
  ]
}
```

Build order

```
client/
  ^
  |
  |
 cmd/
```

#### Node Setup

Best practice is that each sub-project has its own `package.json` file with the [**`main`**](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) property and the [**`name`**](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#name) set. In our example both packages (`cmd/` and `client/`) have a `main` property pointing to the `index.js` file in the TypeScript [`outDir`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) directory (`cmd/dist/index.js` and `client/dist/index.js`).

Project structure:

```
tsconfig.json
cmd/
    tsconfig.json
    package.json
    src/
        index.ts
    dist/  #artifacts
        index.js
client/
    tsconfig.json
    package.json
    src/
        index.ts
    dist/  #artifacts
        index.js
```

`client/packages.json`

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index",
  ...
}
```

It is **important** that we add the **`client/`** as dependency to the **`cmd/packages.json`** so the module resolution algorithm can find the `client/dist/index.js` when we import it in our TypeScript code `import Foo from 'client';`:

`cmd/packages.json`

```
{
  "name": "cmd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index",
  "dependencies": {
    "client": "1.0.0" // important
  }
}
```

`cmd/src/index.ts`

```
import Foo from 'client';

console.log(Foo())
```

#### Yarn Setup

The yarn setup is easy. Yarn adds all packages under `node_modules` instead of:

- `cmd/node_modules`
- `client/node_modules`

To enable yarn [workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) add the `workspaces` property and the `private: true` property to the `<root>/package.json` file.

`<root>/package.json`

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "cmd",
    "client"
  ],
  "name": "yarn_workplace",
  "version": "1.0.0"
  ...
}
```

The `cmd/` and `client/` packages are `symlinked` under the `<root>/node_modules/` directory:

[image: yarn node_modules]

#### Notes

- To enable code navigation one has to first build the project
- Every package lives on its own. The `cmd/` package uses the definition file `client/dist/index.d.ts` for type information instead of using the the TypeScript files directly.

Comment: @devshorts is this working for you? Or are you missing something in my solution?

Comment: great answer. since I posted the question i've already long since set it up this way as well.  My original problem was not understanding that you gotta have the 'dist' folder and if you want the imports to be clean you need to export them from the index module.

Comment: Very nice writeup! I did not find a use for the root-level tsconfig file. Calling tsc on it doesn't build the packages, and it seems redundant unless you want to use it as a base config to inherit from. Since each package still needs their own references setting I don't see that the purpose of the root-level references is.

Comment: If you add a "sub" folder with an "index.ts" in the "src" of the "client" project, and you try to import it from the other project, you get the following error: "TS2307: Cannot find module 'client/sub'". Would you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Finickyflame how are you importing the package? Is the importing project a JavaScript or TypeScript project?

Comment: @a1300 it's a typescript project. I just took your example and tried to add sub dependencies. I was able to make it work by using the "compilerOptions:paths" instead of using "references" in the tsconfig.json

Answer (score -1):

I've set up a monorepo I with some configurations I've always use in my projects using Yarn Workspaces and Typescript in [this repository](https://github.com/arantespp/monorepo-example).

I don't know if this set up solves your problem, but you don't need to specify your packages at Typescript config. When you use Yarn Workspaces, it links all your packages in root `node_modules` that you defined in your workspace package property in your root `package.json`:

```
"workspaces": {
    "packages": [
        "packages/**/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": []
}
```

After `yarn install`, the root `node_modules` has `client` and `cmd` as linked folder.

[image]

With this configuration, you can simply import any package in any package inside the Workspace. For instance:

```
// cmd/src/index.ts

import { name } from 'client';

const otherName = 'cmd' + name;

console.log(otherName);
```

Comment: Build won't work from cmd if you didn't previously build the client. error TS2307: Cannot find module 'client'.

Comment: Did you run `yarn` at the root before try building?

Comment: Yes, of course. Remove all "dist" dir and try yourself.

Comment: I see. With the configuration I propose, you must not remove `dist` folders, it's part of your code. Maybe I completely misunderstood the question and if `dist` shouldn't be part of the repository, my solution won't work.