# Yarn workspaces with typescript SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: typescript, yarn-workspaces

I have application with `typescript` with structure like this:

```
/myapplication
  /packages
    /domain  <- @my-application/domain
    /graphql <- @my-application/graphql
```

`@my-application/graphql` module depend on `@my-application/domain` and when application starting I am getting this error:

```
(node:42497) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: /Users/pavel/Dev/catsapp/packages/domain/index.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { CatCreateInput, Cat } from '@prisma/photon';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:85:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:266:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:314:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

My [tsconfig](https://pastebin.com/PA2k2XDZ) in `@my-application/graphql`.
Why `typescript` doesn't transpiling a `@my-application/domain` module?

**UPDATE:** 
I am added example of repo on [Github](https://github.com/perevezencev/typescript-workspaces)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all packages to main tsconfig.json:

```
"include": [
    "packages"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some more information here : [How to use yarn workspaces with typescript and out folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679322/how-to-use-yarn-workspaces-with-typescript-and-out-folders)

I think you should define your packages paths into your tsconfig file in your root directory.